# Any reason to use WCF to consume non-UTF services?

Tags: c#

I'm confused about the usefulness of WCF in consuming non-UTF services. I decided to try and give it a go, in lieu of .NET 2 web services, and quickly discovered that out-of-box it cannot consume ISO-8859-1 web services. After googling a bit I learned that you need to create a custom message encoder (i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx).

Comparably, if I wanted to use .NET 2's web service model, I just add a reference and it works - no need to write a custom encoder. I've decided to use the easier of the two methods, since I can't justify writing and testing a bunch of code I don't need.

I am however curious why anyone would use WCF when they could use the faster 2.0 method. This is a rudimentary question - I'm new to web services, and just using them to pull data from several third party vendors. All I need is the ability to consume the service, throw some credentials, call methods, and get objects back - I'm assuming WCF goes above and beyond that, somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're doing is consuming an existing non-WCF service, then the choice to go with WCF is probably only going to depend on other factors, like if you anticipate consuming WCF services in the future and want to have a uniform codebase.

WCF is an umbrella with a single interface for multiple "bindings" such as HTTP-with-REST-or-SOAP, named pipes, MSMQ, TCP (formerly .Net Remoting), all mixed in with different options for security, authentication, transactions, reliability, etc. So if you were consuming multiple services that were exposed in a variety of ways, then WCF would help you tame them all with a single API.

Answer (score 1):

Classic web services are by no means 'faster' to employ than WCF services. WCF has only a small learning curve to get going with stuff we used to do with webservices in the past.

Maybe in very simple scenarios you can accomplish the same thing with an asmx web service as you can with a WCF service using a basic HTTP binding, but among the numerous benefits of the framework (industry wide standards, multiple protocol support), is the fact that alot of the plumbing has already been done for you (in terms of communication, security etc), allowing you to focus on your business logic.

Maybe asmx provides what you need, but the technology is deprecated. If you do a google search, there is tons of websites comparing the two. I would advice to take the oppertunity to start learning WCF!

Hope this helps.